# Facebook Graph API Upgrade

Tags: facebook, api, upgrade

I'm working on website that has an old facebook API implementation with Facebook SKD for PHP. I'm not able to update SDK to newer version since it requires PHP 5.4, this project works under 5.3 so I'm forced to use old one.
I have access to API upgrade tool and it shows me a lot of methods that I should fix, for example GET /posts
Assume I want upgrade to v2.4 and I use [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed) to find out what changed in that request. What I found:

> **Deprecated Fields**
>
> As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported
>   by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the
>   parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.
>
> The **link** field is still supported, but its sub-fields have been
>   deprecated.

I feel myself so stupid but I can't realize **what should I use instead of *link* field after it will be deprecated on 17th July**?

Comment: Still using PHP 5.3 is outright dangerous. You are endangering the security and privacy of everyone using your app. http://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: _"what should I use instead of link field after it will be deprecated on 17th July?"_ - no one said the link field was going to be deprecated.

Comment: Ah, so I guess I misunderstood that. Only parameters will be deprecated so. Thank you very much, you can formalize your comment in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what should I use instead of link field after it will be deprecated on 17th July?

The `link` parameter itself is not deprecated; only the "sub fields" that allow you to overwrite the title, caption, description and thumbnail dynamically, are.

This data is now taken exclusively from the Open Graph meta tags the URL posted returns. (With one exception, for page posts it is still possible to at least specify the image to be used dynamically.)